# What is option to change Home dir to user dir?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, live-cd, usb-boot

I'd like to install a new linux system using for i.e: liveCD or USB boot.

But at the time of install new system I'd like to change the name `home` (`home` in `/home/user1`) to `user` (`user` in `/user/user1`)

Is there any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What distribution?

Comment: I try to make it in general but Ubuntu or archlinux would work. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Ubuntu but if it create initial user so I think we should avoid it for general purpose. How about archlinux in this case?

Comment: If you do, please elaborate how to change `initial user account after installation has completed` and then I'll be able to translate it to other platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem not to be familiar with the system you're trying to install, it would be worth discussing this with a colleague who does understand it.

Alternatively use the installation defaults and amend them immediately afterwards. Here is one way to move the initial user's home directory, assuming that the user is called `user1`:

```
usermod --home /user/user1 --move-home user1
```

You can also change the default value for future user accounts:

```
useradd --defaults --base-dir /user
```

Comment: Possible work in step of setting up new user under `chroot` with archlinux.